# AngularJS service TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to capture the url of my query in an AngularJS service as this

```
var mortgageloanService = angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp', []);

mortgageloanService.factory('updateTable', function($http) {

return {
        getParams: function() {

        var url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/angularjs-intro/collections/users?apiKey=terrPcifZzn01_ImGsFOIZ96SwvSXgN9';

                console.log('in service mode');
                console.log(url);
                return $http.get(url);      
    }
};
});
```

This is my controller.js code

```
angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp')
    .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope) {
    $scope.update_result = function(updateTable) {

        updateTable.getParams().success(function(loan){$scope.loan = loan});
        console.log($scope.resulttable);

    };
});
```

On my view page, i have a button which onclick shud call the update_result function. But whenever i click on the button i get the following error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParams' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.update_result (http://localhost:9003/scripts/controllers/mortgage_loan.js:22:16)
    at http://localhost:9003/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10567:21
    at http://localhost:9003/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18627:17
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9003/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12412:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9003/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12510:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9003/bower_components/angular/angular.js:18626:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:9003/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4430:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:9003/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4116:28)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: you haven't injected your fatory into your controller, updateTable  for the controller is a normal var.  .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope) should be .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, updateTable)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your updateTable's factory inside your controller, you need to inject it. So, your controller should look like this.

```
angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp')
    .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, updateTable) {
    $scope.update_result = function() {

        updateTable.getParams().success(function(loan){$scope.loan = loan});
        console.log($scope.resulttable);

    };
});
```

Notice that I've removed "updateTable" as "$scope.update_result"'s parameter since it would overwrite your updateTable object inside that closure.